# How to make chart with two data axis in different sytle

Tags: charts

How to apply different styles on characters `X1` (bold and center/left position) and show `asdasd` (rightposition) in Y-axis of a table??

reality
[image: Fig 1]

edit in paint :)
[image: Fig 2]

Comment: Did you mean Word or Excel? If Word, why don't you edit the chart in Excel before copying it over to Word?

Comment: Sorry @Yax, I really don't understand clearly your point. If Everything is edited in Windows Paint, X1 and asdasd can be easily arranged in Paint as well. If X1 and asdasd are made separately in Word, we can simply 1. highlight X1 then apply bold and center/left to it, and 2. highlight asdasd then apply right position. Can't we? Or I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: @RyanL I think Yax was pointing out that the desired result has been created with Paint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multi-level axis for the category axis.

[image]

If Excel does not recognize the multi-levels, then you can fix that in the data source dialog.

[image]

There is, however, no way to format the axis labels to have different fonts and font sizes for the different levels. Excel simply does not support that.

Edit: there is also no setting to turn the outer level label around. Excel will determine how to show it and there is nothing the user can do to change that.

Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: can apply horizontal for X1 ?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The formatting of the axis labels is not configurable. Excel will do what Excel does and you won't be able to change it. That's not my fault, so you can still mark my post as the answer, because that is the only possible answer.